# Pagination for products, coupons and orders by usin api

Tags: pagination

How to use pagination for products, orders and coupons lists using api? For now i use  SOAP v2. Soap v2 has a filters, but i cant use them for pagination, because they allow to define specific boundary id, e.g. 1 to 10, or less than 400, more than 200. But if products are deleted, pages can be empty. So I need the first 20 records are in the database, rather than the first 20 items with id from 1 to 20. How can this be implemented?